# GPU memory is overloaded

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, gpu

I'm using [iStats Menu](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) to monitor the loading of my MBP.
And when my external 4k monitor LG 27UK850-W is connected via USB type C I can see that my GPU Memory is overloaded (currently 744%), though Processor seems fine.

Is it a bug or it should be this way?

And of course, Fans are almost always on. Is it ok?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared to be an "iStats Menu" issue
And it is fixed in the newest version